# Replace table with dependencies using pandas to_sql's if_exists='replace'

Tags: python, sql, pandas, psql, pandas-to-sql

Pandas `pd.to_sql()` function has the parameter `if_exists='replace'`, which drops the table and inserts the given `DataFrame`. But the table I'm trying to replace is part of a `view`. Is there a way to replace the table and keep the view without having to delete and recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If update has same columns. You can truncate table,

```
con.execute('TRUNCATE table RESTART IDENTITY;')
```

and then run `pd.to_sql` with `if_exists='append'`